# OOP - Normal class to file separated class

Tags: c++, file, oop

I have made a class that works out just fine.
There is no need to try and understand my horrible code.

What I'm asking is: How do I make this class into a class.cpp and header file?

So this one right here is the working version:

```
class Dictionary {

public:

    Dictionary() {
        cout << "Welcome to the constructor" << endl;
    }

void insertWordFun(string word, string lookup, vector<string>& v1, vector<string>& v2) {
    cout << "Accessing add funciton ~" << endl;
    int wordInVector = 0;

    cout << "\nYou chose option #1." << endl;
    cout << "Please insert word: ";
    getline(cin, word);

    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        if (v1[i] == word) {
            cout << "Word already exists." << endl;
            wordInVector = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (wordInVector == 0) {
        v1.push_back(word);
        cout << "Describe your word: ";
        getline(cin, lookup);
        v2.push_back(lookup);
    }
}
};
```

And the code following is when I attempted to separate this class into files and failed:

.h file:

```
#pragma once
class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary();
    void insertWordFun(string word, string lookup, vector<string>& v1, vector<string>& v2);
};
```

Dictionary.cpp (class file):

```
#include "Dictionary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Dictionary::Dictionary(){
    cout << "Welcome to the constructor" << endl;
};

void Dictionary::insertWordFun(string word, string lookup, vector<string>& v1, vector<string>& v2) {
    cout << "Accessing add funciton ~" << endl;
    int wordInVector = 0;

    cout << "\nYou chose option #1." << endl;
    cout << "Please insert word: ";
    getline(cin, word);

    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        if (v1[i] == word) {
            cout << "Word already exists." << endl;
            wordInVector = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (wordInVector == 0) {
        v1.push_back(word);
        cout << "Describe your word: ";
        getline(cin, lookup);
        v2.push_back(lookup);
    }
};
```

Source.cpp (main file):

```
#include "Dictionary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> v1;
    vector<string> v2;
    string word;
    string lookup;
    string choice;

    Dictionary obj;

    while (true) {
        getline(cin, choice);
        if (choice == "1") {
            obj.insertWordFun(word, lookup, v1, v2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include` the headers for the components you use in your header file.  For example, `#include <vector>` needs to be in your header file.

And you need to explicitly specify `std::` in front of the appropriate types in your header, such as `vector` and `string`.  You should not use `using namespace std;` in a header file, but you can use it in your .cpp file.